# App unresponsive in stead of crashing

Tags: android, debugging, crash

This bug has been around for days now for us and we don't seem to be able to fix it.
When there should be an error, our app just hangs and becomes unresponsive instead of crashing.
I've tried everything from clean rebuilding my app to completely deleting it and repulling it.
I've tried it on multiple phones with android 4 & 5, still no luck.
We are using Android Studio 1.2.2

Has anyone else experienced this before and know how to fix it?
It's really frustrating as we aren't able to see where in the code the app crashed.

Thanks!

Comment: This must be the memory leak you are facing,try using mat to identify whats going on.

Comment: Are you using any networking http calls to any websites or webservices during the activity?

Comment: You could try turning on Show All ANRs which will lock the app after 5 seconds of unresponsiveness and let you force the crash.

Settings -> Developer Options -> Apps (last group in list) -> Show all ANRs

Comment: Have you set up Google Analytics in your application?

Answer (score 1):

`Unresponsiveness` in most cases means that some long running operation happens in the `UI thread`. Usually it is disk `IO` operations or some calculations. Network calls on `Android` 3+ just crash app. To find out the reason you can use [`StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) class:

1) You need to add to your app components (Application, Activities) strict mode initialization code:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyFlashScreen()
                .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...your activity cretion code
}
```

2) In the developer settings of your phone you need to enable `Strict mode`.

3) Then launch your app and see what's happening in the `logcat`.

For instance querying 25000 of objects from `SQLite` database using `ORMLite` shows next log:

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=6267 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=2079 violation=2
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1107)
//...
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:181)
//...
at su.sample.android.hz.activities.MainActivity.queryOnUI(MainActivity.java:63)
at su.sample.android.hz.activities.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:23)
at su.sample.android.hz.activities.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
//...
```

It literally shows the line of code which caused violation: `MainActivity.queryOnUI(MainActivity.java:63)`